# cookie name with in array

Tags: php, cookies

```
<?php
//set cookie for testing//

//create var 
$cookie_name1 = 'dee[user]'; //this one cant use 
$cookie_name2 = 'dee'; // but this one can
$age = 'dee15';

setcookie($cookie_name,$age, time()+(60*60*30),'','','',TRUE);    

if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])){
    print 'Cookie with name "' . $cookie_name . '" does not exist...';
}else{
    print 'Cookie with name "' . $cookie_name . '" value is: ' . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
?>
```

What is wrong if I set cookie into `dee[user]` it will return fault ?

And if I just set dee it return true , I really need to put the array inside ? i part didt i did wrong ?

Comment: Your question is unclear but if you're setting a cookie and reading a cookie in the same page, that doesn't work. http://php.net/setcookie is pretty clear that they're not available until the next page load.

Comment: my guess is $cookie_name1 = $dee['user'] u have a typo instead of $cookie_name1 = 'dee[user]'